elasticsearch заменяет значение в индексе ,для поля id на свое
настроено обновление индекса elasticsearch из базы mongodb .
Проблема, в том что в таблицах mongo из которых берутся данные , есть столбец id .
И elasticsearch заменяет значение в индексе ,для id на свое.
--
установлен Elasticsearch Enterprise.
Использую коннектор из репозитория : (вроде разработанный командой Elastic)
https://github.com/elastic/connectors/
В kibana подключаю этот коннектор, синхронизируется по шедулеру(настроенному в kibana)
Не использую логстеш , для синхронизации данных в индексе!
Переименовать столбец в mongo , возможности нет .
Также пробовал в mapping для индекса, указать для поля _source.id директиву copy_to
Копируется, но значение копируется уже измененное.
Есть варианты?

Если не против хардкода в коде коннектора, то можно отредактировать файл /connectors/es/sink.py:
doc_id = doc["id"] = doc.pop("_id")

